# Mocking a WCF service based on a service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, mocking, service-reference

I have a service reference to a WCF service that is hosted by a customer. The service reference has an interface which defines the service contract. I would like to create a service object which implements this interface so that I can add an instance of this to a local Service Host for testing purposes. This way I can fake the data back while still using the same service definition (though making a local endpoint).

The problem I have so far is this: the service only has one method (right now), `GetString`. The contract auto-generated two methods, `GetString` and `GetStringAsync`. It turns out that when I make a service based on an interface, it automatically generates an async method for each of the defined methods. Which means that my new service now has four methods:

- `GetString`
- `GetStringAsync`
- `GetStringAsync`
- `GetStringAsyncAsync`

If you caught that middle section, there are now two `GetStringAsync`s, which prevents the service from starting.

Is there a way I can host a service based on a ServiceReference so that I can keep the same interface? If possible, I would like to prevent just duplicating the defined methods of the service reference in a secondary, as then I can just update the definition and the compiler will notify me when there are new things I need to implement. Also if I do that, my client library (which I want to have as much shared code as possible) will have to have two separate service reference instead of just a configurable endpoint and remote host that I can pass into the client constructor.

Comment: You can share your interface in a separate assembly. Thus, when you reference this assembly, you need to implement just the methods declared in the interface.

Comment: I don't control the definition of the initial service, it's customer hosted and defined. The only thing I have is the resulting Service Reference. In the Service Reference it defines the two methods listed in the post, because the Async version is automatically generated.

Comment: I understood. Did you add the reference with Add -> Service Reference? If so, if you click Advanced button, there is an aption called "Generate task-based operations" that must be selected. You can also generate your proxy with svutil.exe and the option /syncOnly